# Making df columns unique to one column permanently outside of df loop function

Tags: python, pandas, global-variables, unique, drop-duplicates

*Note: Correction - the code returns AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'*

I am trying to loop through a number of dfs and reduce my 'user_id' column to only unique values using the 
`df.drop_duplicates(subset =['user_id']`
function.

I need this to be a global change and am trying to incorporate it into my function that imports .csv files and assigns them to their file name. This works perfectly but when I try and add the drop_duplicates function, it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
def assign_vars(files = os.listdir()):
    # Make list of variable names using file name
    variables = [make_var(file) for file in files]
    # Start list to place dfs into
    dfs = []
    for var,file in zip(variables,files):
        # Use globals to assign dfs to file names
        globals()[var] = pd.read_csv(file)
        #<<1>>
        # Add each newly made df var to a list
        dfs.append(var.drop_duplicates(subset =['user_id'])) # rmv duplicates
    return print('Your variables are: ',sorted(dfs))
```

*This returns an attribute error.It seems that the var is being treated as a str instead of a df*

When I  `len()` a df, they remain the same as before. Even though when I individually `df.drop_duplicates` they shorten in `len()` by about 70%.

Alternatively, I have tried to make a mid object at <<1>> and then `.drop_duplicates`. This doesn't work and I believe its because the change is staying local.

Comment: dfs = dfs.append(var.drop_duplicates(subset =['user_id'])). You need to assign the modified df back. Can you make this change and check once.

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast response. However, this fix returns: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'. I realised that this error also arrises with my previous code, I just hadn't called the function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix

Adding `.drop_duplicates(subset =['user_id'])` to the end of the csv import, as they become globalised seemed to do the trick.

```
def assign_vars(files = os.listdir()):
    # Make list of variable names using file name
    variables = [make_var(file) for file in files]
    # Start list to place dfs into
    dfs = []
    for var,file in zip(variables,files):
        # Use globals to assign dfs to file names
        globals()[var] = pd.read_csv(file).drop_duplicates(subset =['user_id'])
        # Add each newly made df var to a list
        dfs.append(var) # rmv duplicates
    return print('Your variables are: ',sorted(dfs))
```